# Is there a way to cache container image downloads by GitHub Actions' built-in container functionality?

Tags: continuous-integration, containers, github-actions

GitHub Actions has built-in functionality for running jobs in Docker containers ([`jobs.<job_id>.container`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer)). A minimal example using it would look like this:

```yaml
name: Test workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  test_job_running_in_container:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: quay.io/pypa/manylinux_2_24_x86_64
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
    steps:
    - name: say hello
      run: echo hello!
```

However, when I run jobs in containers in this way, a lot of time is spent re-downloading the container's FS layers again on each run. E.g. [here](https://github.com/smheidrich/dummy-gha-container-nocache/runs/3247569485?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:15) is a CI run for the example above, showing it took 22 seconds just for the container setup, most of which goes into downloading it. Considering all this happens "outside" of regular job execution, which then takes place within the container, the normal method of caching using the `actions/cache` action can't work. Hence my question:

Is there a way to cache container downloads performed by GitHub Actions' built-in container functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind actually, it seems that this simply isn't currently supported by GitHub, with no plans for support anytime soon: https://github.community/t/docker-layer-caching/17212 ([Internet Archive version](https://web.archive.org/web/20200801000000*/https://github.community/t/docker-layer-caching/17212)).

Waste of time and bandwidth.