# How to cache container images for a job running inside a container

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

According to the docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container), entire jobs can be run inside a container, like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: "texlive/texlive:latest"
```

How can I cache this container image to speed up further runs?

Comment: in the shared runner environment, image will be cached if both jobs run on the same runner. otherwise it'll always pull image. If you want to speed up your pipeline, I suggest caching dependencies or other thing using artifacts instead. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts

Comment: See this answer - does not look like this is supported currently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659555/is-there-a-way-to-cache-container-image-downloads-by-github-actions-built-in-co/68660121#68660121